# Is there a way of rendering markdown within a Webview

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, vscode-extensions

I'm writing an extension that displays content in a webview - just text at the moment, but I also want to output markdown (.md) within my content - so text and markdown. Is this possible? I need to keep all the formatting and render the markdown, does any one know how to do this?

Comment: Hello!

Just to be sure: _"I need to keep all the formatting and render the markdown"_. Do you want to render the raw markdown code? The formatted output (e.g. preview of the markdown)? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, render the markdown like preview sees it (so # becomes h1, ## h2 etc.) but within my already existig webview with other content. This isn't a separate webview that just displays markdown.

Comment: VCS has a Markdown viewer. "Markdown: Open preview on the side". If needed you can look at the source code to get the transform to HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying!

I think you can use **a markdown parser** to convert the raw markdown into the same language you're using for your content.

For example, if the rest of your content is HTML, you can probably use https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it to get inline HTML from the markdown and inject that in your page.

If your content is JSX, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx, etc.